# How can I access a derived class' methods if it is returned as the base class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm creating a state machine that allows you to add states onto a stack. Here are a couple methods it contains:

```
void pushState(State* state);

State* getCurrentState();
```

`State` is just a base class that is meant to be used to create derived classes. So I created a derived class called `GameState` and it has a unique method called `foo`. If I do something like the following, it won't let me access `foo` because "No method named 'foo' exists for class State.

```
State* currentState = myStateMachine.getCurrentState();
```

I also tried changing `State*` to `GameState*`, but it doesn't work because `getCurrentState()` returns type `State`. How can I get the current state on the stack when I don't actually know what derived state is the current one?

I also don't know why it allows me to push `GameState` onto a stack that is expecting `State`, but won't let me retrieve it as `GameState`. Instead it makes me retrieve it at `State`.

Comment: How do you derive `GameState` from `State`? Did you use the `virtual` keyword?

Comment: @thb I just did `class GameState : public State`

Comment: Have you read, in your C++ book, how to create virtual functions?

Comment: Create a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can really see the code you wrote instead of guessing from your description.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the type State* to GameState*

I mean:

```
State* currentState = myStateMachine.getCurrentState();
```

should be

```
// if State class don't have any virtual method, you should use static_cast<>
GameState* currentState = static_cast<GameState*>(myStateMachine.getCurrentState());
```

or

```
// if State class has at least virtual method, you should use dynamic_cast<>
GameState* currentState = dynamic_cast<GameState*>(myStateMachine.getCurrentState());
```

It will work

Comment: Ofc you should prefer to not c-style cast, and instead write the correct cast, which will save trouble if `getCurrentState` changes its return or `GameState` stops inheriting `State`

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` and check the result for null before using it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    class State {
    public:
        virtual int foo() const = 0;
    };
    class GameState : public State {
    public:
        int foo() const { return 5; }
    };
}

int main() {
    const GameState s{};
    std::cout << s.foo() << "\n";
    const State *const p = &s;
    std::cout << p->foo() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For `GameState` to replace the method `foo()` of `State` in C++, the method must be virtual.  The reason is that, by default, for efficiency, the C++ compiler computes the address of `foo()` at compile time. The `virtual` keyword indirects the address through a pointer to a structure that lists the virtual methods of the `GameState` type.

Your problem is that, unless `foo()` is virtual, your computer has no way to tell at run time whether a `State *` object points to a `State` object or a `GameState` object.

However, if `foo()` is virtual, then every `State` object including `GameState` objects includes a pointer that points to a hidden *vtable.* The `State` *type* has one *vtable.*  The `GameState` type has another *vtable.*  Each *vtable* refers to the proper function `foo()`.

[The `= 0` in the example, incidentally, informs the compiler that no actual function `foo()` will be provided for `State` objects proper. You can omit the `= 0` in your code and instead provide a `State::foo()` if you wish.]